# time elapsed with pause logic mysql TIMEDIFF() and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got this query that takes my elapsed_time and that works fine but then I realized I'm getting the value of actual_elapsed wrong. actual_elapsed is the running time of my timer that I take by using TIMEDIFF(). log_time is a datetime, it is the datetime when the action (play, pause) was inserted/made. sequence is int, it tells me which happened first for each user. status, also int, tells me if the action made was play(1), pause(2) or stop(3).

Like I said my problem is getting the right value for actual_elapsed by using TIMEDIFF(now(), log_time). It would've been just fine if I didn't have a pause action.

Example DB Entry

```
log_time               sequence     status

2012-09-27 15:31:02     1            1                
2012-09-27 15:31:04     2            2               **2  +**
2012-09-27 15:40:08     3            1
2012-09-27 15:40:45     4            2               **39 +**
2012-09-27 15:40:47     5            1
2012-09-27 15:40:57     6            3               **10 =**
                                                     **49**
```

My query gives me 09 minutes and 57 seconds, when I should only be getting 49 seconds.

My SAMPLE Query.

```
 (" select sequence_num, elapsed_time, status, TIMEDIFF(now(), log_time) as actual_elapsed from tbl");
```

I'm trying to get the duration of the actual_elapsed. To do that I'd have to somehow take the total duration of the break time (pause) and then get the difference of elapsed_time and the break time. But I'm having trouble on that part also since the user can pause the timer multiple times.

This seemed simple enough when I designed my DB. How do I go about this without so much mess?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT iStop-iStart FROM 
(SELECT SUM(log_time) AS iStop FROM tbl WHERE status IN (2,3)) a JOIN
(SELECT SUM(log_time) AS iStart FROM tbl WHERE status=1) b;

Above query only work if pause or stop is last record